# Can't capture multiple http requests to different url's from Angular service method in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, httprequest

I'm looking to test a service method in Angular using Jasmine and Karma Runner that makes two HTTP requests to two separate URL's. However, my test captures the first request, but not the second.

- The service

  - The service, stage-loader.service.ts, makes an http request to https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stages.json to get a JSON array of summary stage information (name, gameName, Type). It then uses the gameName property of each stage summary to request a JSON array of each stage's details from https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stage/[gameName]/data.json. Finally it assigns those details to each stage summary's [detail] property and returns the edited array.
- The test

  - The test uses mock data in place of actual http calls: A stage summary array containing one stage, and the details for that stage. The test is to determine whether the service method, loadStages() makes two HTTP requests and returns an Observable with an array of one stage summary, with an appended details property, with data provided from the mock data files.
- The issue

  - When I run the jasmine test, the console logs tell me that the first http request is made, but the service doesn't get far enough in execution to let the test detect the second http request.

The service code:

```js
  loadStages(): Observable<Stage[]> {
    /**/console.log('StageLoaderService::loadStages() called.');
    let stagesObs: Observable<Stage[]> = new Observable((observer) => {

      let stages: Stage[] = [];

      const { next, error } = observer;

      // get stage summary data
      let summariesObs: Observable<Stage[]> = this._http.get<Stage[]>(API_URL + API_STAGE_LIST_PATH);
      /**/console.log('  * created summariesObs');

      summariesObs.subscribe((summaries) => {
        /**/console.log('  * summariesObs emitted: ' + JSON.stringify(summaries));

        // subscribe to _getStageDetails, providing summaries
        let stageObs: Observable<Stage> = this._getStageDetails(summaries);
        stageObs.subscribe({
          next(stage) {
            /**/console.log('    + summariesObs.subscribe - stageObs emitted: ' + JSON.stringify(stage));
            stages.push(stage);
          },

          error() {},
          complete() {
            /**/console.log('    + summariesObs.subscribe - stageObs complete');
            observer.next(stages);
          }
        });
      });
      /**/console.log('  * subscribed to summariesObs');

      return { unsubscribe(): void { } };

    });

    /**/console.log('  * returning stagesObs');
    return stagesObs;
  }

  _getStageDetails(summaries: Stage[]): Observable<Stage> {
    /**/console.log('StageLoaderService::_getStageDetails() called.');
    /**/console.log('  * summaries passed in: ' + JSON.stringify(summaries));

    let detailsObs = new Observable<Stage>((observer) => {
      /**/console.log('  * detailsObs executing');
      // for each summary in summaries
      for (let i = 0; i < summaries.length; i++) {
        /**/console.log('    + detailsObs - summary: ' + JSON.stringify(summaries[i]));
        let url = API_URL + API_STAGE_DETAILS_PREFIX + summaries[i].name + API_STAGE_DETAILS_PATH;

        /**/console.log('    + retrieving details from url: ' + url);
        // retrieve json
        this._http.get<StageDetails[]>(url).subscribe((details) => {
          /**/console.log('    + detailsObs - retrieved details: ' + JSON.stringify(details));
          summaries[i].details = details;
          observer.next(summaries[i]);
          if (i === summaries.length - 1) {
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      }

    });

    return detailsObs;
  }
```

The test code

```js
describe('StageLoaderService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: StageLoaderService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        StageLoaderService
      ]
    });

    injector = getTestBed();
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = injector.get(StageLoaderService);
  }));

  describe('loadStages()', () => {
    it(`should return an Observable Stages array composed of stage list data and stage details data`, async(() => {
      let stageList = STAGE_LIST.PRINCESS_PEACH_CASTLE;
      /**/console.log('SPEC - stageList: ' + JSON.stringify(stageList));
      let stageDetails = STAGE_DETAILS.PRINCESS_PEACH_CASTLE;
      let expectedStages = STAGES.PRINCESS_PEACH_CASTLE;

      service.loadStages().subscribe((actualStages) => {
        /**/console.log('SPEC - actualStages: ' + JSON.stringify(actualStages));
        expect(actualStages.length).toBe(1);
        expect(actualStages).toEqual(expectedStages);
      });
      /**/console.log('SPEC - subscribed to service.loadStages()');

      let requests = httpMock.match((req) => {
        /**/console.log('SPEC - httpMock.match() - returning request');
        return (
          (req.url == 'https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stages.json')
          || (req.url == `https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stage/Princess Peach's Castle/data.json`)
          || (req.url == `https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stage/Princess%20Peach's%20Castle/data.json`));
      });

      expect(requests.length).toEqual(2);
      /**/console.log('SPEC - requests: ' + JSON.stringify(requests[0].request));

      const REQ_STAGE_LIST = requests[0];
      /**/console.log('SPEC - REQ_STAGE_LIST set');

      const REQ_STAGE_DETAILS = requests[1];
      /**/console.log('SPEC - REQ_STAGE_DETAILS set');

      expect(REQ_STAGE_LIST.request.method).toBe("GET");
      /**/console.log('SPEC - REQ_STAGE_LIST method checked');

      expect(REQ_STAGE_DETAILS.request.method).toBe("GET");
      /**/console.log('SPEC - REQ_STAGE_DETAILS method checked');

      REQ_STAGE_LIST.flush(stageList);
      /**/console.log('SPEC - REQ_STAGE_LIST flushed');

      REQ_STAGE_DETAILS.flush(stageDetails);
      /**/console.log('SPEC - REQ_STAGE_DETAILS flushed');

    }));

    afterEach(async(() => {
      /**/console.log('SPEC - verifying httpMock');
      httpMock.verify();
    }));
  });
});
```

This is the Karma Runner output:

```
StageLoaderService > loadStages() > should return an Observable Stages array composed of stage list data and stage details data
Expected 1 to equal 2.
```

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
```

Here are the console logs:

```
SPEC - stageList: [{"name":"Princess Peach's Castle","gameName":"mario_castledx_","Type":0}]      context.js:255
StageLoaderService::loadStages() called.      context.js:255
  * returning stagesObs     context.js:255
  * created summariesObs      context.js:255
  * subscribed to summariesObs      context.js:255
SPEC - subscribed to service.loadStages()     context.js:255
SPEC - httpMock.match() - returning request     context.js:255
SPEC - requests: {"url":"https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stages.json","body":null,"reportProgress":false,"withCredentials":false,"responseType":"json","method":"GET","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"params":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"urlWithParams":"https://rubendal.github.io/ssbu/data/patch/3.1.0/stages.json"}     context.js:255
SPEC - REQ_STAGE_LIST set     context.js:255
SPEC - REQ_STAGE_DETAILS set      context.js:255
SPEC - REQ_STAGE_LIST method checked      context.js:255
SPEC - verifying httpMock      context.js:255
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by abandoning Angular's TestBed approach entirely, since it seems it isn't great at detecting an http request that depends on data from a previous http request.

Instead, I used Jasmine's Spy approach.

The new test code:

```
describe('StageLoaderService', () => {
  let service: StageLoaderService;
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };

  beforeEach(() => {
    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    service = new StageLoaderService(<any> httpClientSpy);
  });

  describe('loadStages()', () => {
    it(`should return an Observable Stages array composed of stage list data and stage details data`, async(() => {
      let stageList = STAGE_LIST.PRINCESS_PEACH_CASTLE;
      /**/console.log('SPEC - stageList: ' + JSON.stringify(stageList));
      let stageDetails = STAGE_DETAILS.PRINCESS_PEACH_CASTLE;
      let expectedStages = STAGES.PRINCESS_PEACH_CASTLE;

      httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValues(asyncData(stageList), asyncData(stageDetails));

      let actualStagesObs = service.loadStages();
      /**/console.log('SPEC - obtained observable from service.loadStages()');

      actualStagesObs.subscribe((actualStages) => {
        /**/console.log('SPEC - actualStages: ' + JSON.stringify(actualStages));
        expect(actualStages.length).toBe(1);
        expect(actualStages).toEqual(expectedStages);
        expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(2);
      });
      /**/console.log('SPEC - subscribed to service.loadStages()');
    }));
```